# Is there any possibility to just open a piece of code in a separate tab/section in Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, intellij-idea

I know the that we can close the sections of the code [as mentioned here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-folding.html)

Imagine a jsp file and you want to change a part of code (e.g from lines 100 -150 in 700 jsp file)

It would be easy for any one to select the code and open in any of below mentioned scenarios

- popup
- permanently highlight the background
- new tab

Do intellij/eclipse supports any of the above mentioned feature even with plugins ?

Comment: I don't even understand your question: What are these "sections" that you talk about? How do you "close a section"?

Comment: @StephenFriedrich I have added the link of what I am referring to, apologies for my previous question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to open only the code fold in another editor.

What I do is I split the editor, for example right-click on the editor tab and select Split Vertically or Horizontally. Then you'll get another editor window showing the same file. Expanding/collapsing code folds in one window will not affect the other window.

There is a great, related feature that however only works in specialized cases, where IDEA detects (automatically or via annotation) that a region contains another language, for example:

```
    //language=HTML
    String foo ="<div>Tralala</div>";
```

Here you *can* press alt-enter on the string and select "Edit HTML Fragment" to see only the string content in a new editor window.
In many cases IDEA automatically detects that the language, in other cases it needs help (alt-enter, then "Inject language or reference").

Comment: thanks for the language annotation, I know there is no such editor but was not sure whether there is a plugin :)